# Help with the circular equations with powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $12^a=2$ and $6^b=3$, I am trying to find $2^{2ab(1-b)}$. The answer should be $9$. I did a couple of thing, but the most promising one at least to me is the following:

$$
6^a 2^a=2\\
6^b=3
$$
Now taking the power $b$ of the first equation and taking the power $a$ of the second equation, and some cancellations yield $2^{ab}=\frac{2^b}{3^a}$. This can be rearranged as

$$ 
2^{-a(1-b)}=\frac{2^b}{2^a 3^a}=\frac{2^b}{6^a}=\frac{2^b}{2^{(1-a)}}
$$

I could not get anything meaningful from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I see that $6^{1-b}=6\cdot\frac{1}{3} = 2 =12^a.$

Comment: "The answer should be 9" It is not. Please check possible typos.

Answer (score 0):

from the second equation we get $$b=\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(6)}$$ and fro´m the first one
$$12^a=2$$ thus $$a=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(12)}$$
and your term $$2^{2ab(1-b)}=2^{2\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(12)}\cdot\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(6)}\left(1-\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(6)}\right)}$$